# Calling a class function from a Vector instead of an Array

Tags: c++, arrays, class, function, vector

I am currently working on a way to load a bunch of different NPCs from a file and loading it into my game.  I have everything working correctly with arrays but I would like to change it to using a vector since I can change the size in case I need more NPCs than the space available in the array and so I don't just have a mostly empty array if I dont need many NPCs at the current time. Note that the following code is from a testing program, not my actual programming. I made it so I dont mess with the complete project by accident.

```
int main()
{
char input;
bool Running = true;
NPC Creatures[MAX_NPCS];

//InitCreatures loads the X, Y and Type from the file. I know with vectors I have to
//resize it as I go along, Which would be included in the function.
if(Creatures[MAX_NPCS].InitCreatures(Creatures) == false)
{
    Creatures[MAX_NPCS].CleanUp(Creatures);
    return 0;
}

while(Running == true)
{
    cout << "(C)heck an NPC, (A)ttack and NPC or (E)xit the program\n";
    cin >> input;
    switch(input)
    {
        case 'C': Creatures[MAX_NPCS].Check(Creatures); break;
        case 'c': Creatures[MAX_NPCS].Check(Creatures); break;
        //The Check function just shows the X, Y and Type of the NPC
        case 'A': Creatures[MAX_NPCS].Attack(Creatures); break;
        case 'a': Creatures[MAX_NPCS].Attack(Creatures); break;
        //Attack shows X, Y and type and then removes that NPC from the array.
        case 'E': Running = false; break;
        case 'e': Running = false; break;
        default: cout << "That was not a valid input\n"; break;
    }
}

Creatures[MAX_NPCS].CleanUp(Creatures);
cout << "Exiting\n";
system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

Really the only problem I am having is getting Main to run the NPC Class functions from a vector instead of using the Array like I have now. I can easily change the other things in the functions I'm calling to accept the vector and handle it correctly.

When trying to use a vector to run the functions I was only able to call them when I had something like this:

```
Creatures[1].Attack(Creatures);
```

Of course when I call them like that the values don't return correctly and I usually get an error and Besides I don't know how many NPCs will be loaded for the current map, if Any.

Any help with this would be appreciated. I realize I am a newbie when it comes to programming, especially when it comes to Vectors.  If my function code is needed I will gladly post it.

Comment: Erm, an access like `Creatures[MAX_NPCS]` is undefined behaviour. You only have indices up to `MAX_NPCS-1` available.

Comment: Oh oops, Good catch. Kind of also why I want vectors. But I feel like I'm not understanding them correctly. Anyway the functions have protection that keeps you from adding too many NPCs and does it properly :P

Comment: `std::vector` is nothing more than a good packaged dynamic array. Just `.push_back` things into it, and get them with normal array access (`operator[]`). What does your programming book say about it?

Comment: Yeah, basically what I understood is that a vector is a resizable array. Which is why I wanted to use it for this program. Since I dont know exactly how many NPCs there will be per map. So exactly how would I run my functions from the vector? The current array set up works fine with storing the X, Y and type of the NPC. But I cant get the vector to call the commands unless I specify how many NPCs there are beforehand, which I wont know until InitCreatures is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just create a vector and have the first element in there to be able to call the InitCreatures function (you could also overwrite the first creature later).

```
vector<NPC> Creatures(1);
Creatures[0].InitCreatures(Creatures);
```

I'm assuming that in class you have the parameter passed by reference.

```
bool InitCreatures(vector<NPC>& x) { ... }
```

But since you give creatures as a parameter to every function you have (do you need it in check or attack?) - wouldn't it be better to have a class to hold the NPC vector?

Comment: That works up until the point when I need to add more to the vector. Since all the NPC's are loaded within that function how do I resize the vector. If I try to in the function then well, my computer doesn't like it.

Comment: Ah, nevermind. It seems to have been something else. For some odd reason its working fine now. I just forgot to change some things when converting from Arrays I think. Thank you for your help!